# "Absentiv" oder doch was anderes

Tags: grammar, terminology

Konstruktionen wie die folgende werden manchmal als [Absentiv](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absentiv) bezeichnet.

> Ich bin einkaufen.

Dieser ist beschränkt auf das Verb "sein" und ich frage mich, ob diese Kategorie wirklich sinnvoll ist, da es nur einen von 3 Konstruktionen beschreibt, die im Grunde alle gleich aufgebaut sind (nicht-Modalverb mit Infinitiv ohne "zu") und den gleichen Inhalt aus verschiedener Perspektive darstellen (Information über wo man ist kombiniert mit was man macht)

> Ich gehe demonstrieren.
>   Ich bin demonstrieren.
>   Ich komme demonstrieren.

- Gibt es grammatische Bezeichnungen für die Versionen mit "gehen"  und "kommen"? Wenn nicht:
- Ist es wirklich sinnvoll, eine dieser 3 Formen als "Absentiv" zu bezeichnen bzw. sollten dann nicht auch die anderen beiden Formen Namen bekommen?

Comment: Ich befürchte, dass ist "personal opinion". Ich finde den Absentiv nicht sinnvoll (also aufs Deutsche bezogen). Andere mögen eine andere Sicht darauf haben.

Comment: Ich stimme Em1 zu, in beiden Punkten. Der unter "Einzelnachweis 3" vom Wikipedia-Artikel verlinkte Artikel von Prof. Ickler findet ihn fürs Deutsche auch nicht sinnvoll. Die Konstruktionen mit "gehen" und "kommen" gibt es übrigens auch in anderen Sprachen (z.B. im Japanischen, da gibt es von dieser Sorte noch viele andere), aber ich kenne keinen offiziellen Namen dafür.

Comment: Das liegt an der Fragestellung, jede Frage der Form `Ist [...] wirklich sinnvoll?` kann als "primarily opinion based" abgetan werden. Könntet ihr zumindest begründen, *warum* diese (oder überhaupt eine) Bezeichnung ungeeignet ist?

Comment: @Grantwalzer Für mich vermittelt der Satz "Ich bin einkaufen" *nicht* die Aussage, dass ich mich nicht an einem Ort befinde, sondern wenn schon, dass ich mich an einem Ort befinde. Klar, ruft man mich zu Hause an und ein Mitbewohner sagt dem Anrufer, dass ich einkaufen sei (und somit abwesend), ist die Bedingung für den Absentiv erfüllt. Ruft man mich auf dem Handy an, und ich sage, ich sei einkaufen, so vermittel ich aber, dass ich mich in einem (unbestimmten) Geschäft befinde (oder im Auto auf dem Weg zum Geschäft?). Aber von "Abwesenheit" ist keine Rede.

Comment: @Em1 Die Fragen (denn es sind ja mehrere) lassen sich zumindest zu einem großen Teil durchaus mit Fakten und Forschungsergebnissen beantworten. Grantwalzer hat das versucht und ich gerade auch. Von daher finde ich nicht, daß die Frage aus sich heraus nur Antworten generieren muß, die hauptsächlich persönliche Meinungen transportieren. Ich wäre insbesondere interessiert, aus den Antworten anhand eines konkreten Beispiels ablesen zu können, wie Begriffsfindung unter Grammatikern abläuft, also welche Argumente dabei zum Tragen kommen.

Comment: @Matthias Wohlbemerkt habe ich nicht den close vote abgegeben, weil durchaus Spielraum besteht, in dem man seine Meinung sinnvoll argumentieren kann. Dennoch, ob man es als sinnvoll ansieht, in den Satz "Ich bin einkaufen" soviel hineinzuinterpretieren, dass er eine Abwesenheit deklariert (die imho eben nicht per se stattfindet), das ist persönliche Meinung. Für mich ist die Aussagekraft eine ganz andere, nämlch "Ich bin *einkaufen*!" Das ist kein Absentiv, sondern ein Tätigkeits-sentiv ;)

Comment: @Em1 Zu dem "Tätigkeits-sentiv": da hab ich auch schon drüber gegrübelt. Aber würde man nicht sagen "Ich kaufe ein", wenn es vorrangig um die Tätigkeit geht?

Answer (score 8):

Ich bin auf diesen Fachartikel aufmerksam geworden: ["Alle sind Deutschland ... außer Fritz Eckenga – der ist einkaufen!"](http://pub.ids-mannheim.de/laufend/opal/pdf/opal09-4_koenig.pdf) von [Svenja König](http://www.innatura.org/our-staff/svenja-koenig/). In Kapitel 8 geht König dort genau auf die in der Frage angesprochene Gruppe "sein / gehen / kommen + Infinitiv" ein.

Die erste Frage beantwortet sie indirekt mit "Nein" - wenn es für die Versionen mit "gehen" und "kommen" eine etablierte grammatikalische Bezeichnung gäbe, müßte sie sie eigentlich benutzen oder zumindest benennen. Tut sie aber nicht.

Zur zweiten Frage, insbesondere zu deren zweitem Teil, paßt diese Passage (S. 60):

> Die Besonderheit des Absentivs, die ihn als Konstruktion von den
>   anderen infinitivregierenden Verben  und auch denen des Paradigmas [die sein/gehen/kommen-Gruppe]
>   abgrenzt, besteht darin, dass sich seine Bedeutung eben nicht aus der 
>   lexikalischen Bedeutung des finiten Verbs erschließen lässt, sondern
>   nur mit Hinblick auf die grammatische  Bedeutung,  die  dieses  in 
>   der  Konstruktion  erhält.  Diese  Unmöglichkeit  der  Ableitung  der 
>   Absentivbedeutung  aus  seinen  lexikalischen  Bestandteilen  ist 
>   genau  der  Grund  dafür,  dass  absentivisches  sein eine 
>   Sonderstellung  innerhalb  des  Paradigmas  und  generell  gegenüber 
>   den  anderen  Verben, die einen Infinitiv fordern, einnimmt. Während
>   sich bei der  gehen-Konstruktion die absentivische Bedeutung aus den
>   Komponenten ergibt, indem der im Verb inhärente (Weg-)
>   Bewegungscharakter von gehen mit einem Verb, welches die beabsichtigte
>   Tätigkeit beschreibt, kombiniert wird,  ergibt sich die Bedeutung von 
>   sein  + Infinitiv im Absentiv nicht kompositionell aus seinen
>   Bestandteilen und kann daher auch nicht erschlossen werden, wenn man
>   nicht um die Gesamtbedeutung der  Konstruktion weiß.

D.h. nach meinem Verständnis, sie befürwortet eine Heraushebung der Konstruktion mit "sein" gegenüber den beiden anderen durch einen eigenen Begriff, weil hier die Bedeutung nicht mehr aus den Wörtern abgeleitet werden könne, sondern auf die grammatikalische Konstruktion übergegangen sei.

Theodor Ickler hingegen widerspricht in dem schon von [Grantwalzer angeführten](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/15531/9091) und auch im [Wikipedia-Artikel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absentiv) als Referenz angegebenen Artikel [Kein „Absentiv“ im Deutschen](http://www.sprachforschung.org/ickler/index.php?show=news&id=1278):

> Es ist richtig, diese Verwendung des Verbs sein in die Wörterbücher
>   aufzunehmen, aber nicht als „absentives sein“. ... Anders als König
>   meine ich, daß die Konstruktion sich sehr wohl „unter eine andere,
>   bereits bestehende Konstruktion subsumieren lässt“ (König 2009:65).
>   Die Bedeutungskomponente der „Abwesenheit“ ist ein vorhersagbarer
>   Nebeneffekt des finalen Infinitivs in einigen seiner Verwendungen.

Ickler plädiert also für eine Einordnung der Konstruktion (und wohl auch der Varianten mit "kommen" und "gehen") als Abart des "[finalen Infinitiv](http://www.sprachforschung.org/ickler/index.php?show=news&id=1602)".

Zur Semantik der "sein + Infinitiv"-Konstruktion und damit letztlich zur Frage, ob der Begriff "Absentiv" sinnvoll gewählt ist, gibt es am Anfang von Königs Arbeit längere Betrachtungen - eindeutig bejahend, wie ich meine.

Interessant fand ich hierzu den Einwand von [Em1](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/1224/em1) in seinem Kommentar:

> Für mich vermittelt der Satz "Ich bin einkaufen" nicht die Aussage, dass ich mich nicht an einem Ort befinde, sondern wenn schon, dass ich mich an einem Ort befinde.

Zunächst ist dieser Satz offenbar nach manchen Quellen *per Definition* kein Absentiv, denn Ickler schreibt:

> Abraham legt die Konstruktion definitorisch auf „Abwesenheit“ fest und schließt deshalb die erste und zweite Person aus, weil Sprecher und Hörer nicht außerhalb der Kommunikationssituation sein können. Wenn man aber die Konstruktion „Subjekt + Verb sein (finit) + Handlungsverb (Infinitiv)“ unvoreingenommen untersuchen will, darf man sich nicht auf jene Verwendungsweisen beschränken, die einer vorgefaßten Ansicht über ihre Funktion entsprechen.

Auch König wendet sich gegen diese Einschränkung (zitiert nach Ickler, der dafür keine Quelle nennt):

> In der heutigen Zeit ist aber dank moderner Kommunikationsmittel vieles möglich, auch ein Absentiv in der ersten Person im Präsens. Der Satz *Ich bin einkaufen* klingt als Antwort auf die Frage „Wo bist du?“ übers Handy ganz passabel. Während ich dies sage, bin ich im Normalfall für die Person am anderen Ende der Telefonverbindung abwesend.

Desweiteren schreibt König auf S. 42 (das verlinkte Dokument beginnt mit S. 41!):

> Beim Topikort handelt es sich typischerweise um einen Ort, an dem die fragliche Person normalerweise anzutreffen ist bzw. an welchem ihre 
>   Anwesenheit innnerhalb des Diskurses zu erwarten ist. Der Topikort ist in jedem Fall verschieden vom 
>   Absentivort, an dem das absentivische Ereignis stattfindet.

Ickler bemerkt dazu:

> Damit wird immerhin Vogels Festlegung auf das „deiktische Zentrum“, also wohl den Ort des Gesprächs (so versteht es auch Abraham: „the speaker's place“), relativiert – eine, wie sich zeigen wird, notwendige Korrektur.

Mir fällt dabei noch auf, daß in diesem Beispiel zwar durchaus die Abwesenheit aus Sicht des Anrufers gegeben ist, die Definition für Topikort nach König hingegen eher nicht zutrifft: man kann in dieser Situation dem Anrufer im Allgemeinen nicht eine bestimmte Erwartung hinsichtlich des Aufenthaltsortes des Subjektes unterstellen. Ich fände das reparabel, wenn König "typischerweise" statt "in jedem Fall" schreiben würde oder den Fall eines unbekannten Topikortes mit aufnähme. Die Referenz auf "Abwesenheit" im Begriff des Absentivs träfe dann immer noch auf viele Anwendungen der Konstruktion zu und ist m.E. hilfreich, das Konzept zu erklären. Möglicherweise trifft sie aber tatsächlich nicht die "Essenz" der Aussagen. Jedenfalls kritisiert Ickler:

> Zwar implizieren alle Beispiele, daß der Betreffende sich anderswohin begeben hat, um die genannte Tätigkeit auszuüben, aber die Abwesenheit ist nicht der eigentliche Inhalt der Aussage.

Er sieht den eigentlichen Kern in der Angabe von Ziel und Zweck einer Handlung und plädiert deshalb, wie schon geschrieben, für die Einordnung als "finaler Infinitiv".

Comment: Das dritte Zitat ist ein toller Fund. An das erste Zitat schließt der erste Kommentar von Claus K. in dem von mir verlinkten Artikel an.

Comment: @Grantwalzer Das dritte Zitat von König (nach meinem Edit ist es nun das sechste insgesamt in der Antwort) fand auch Ickler schon so toll, daß er es dem von Dir herangezogenen Artikel verwendet ;-) Den erwähnten Kommentar von Claus K. finde ich auch spannend. Er ist ja noch nicht so alt - mal sehen, ob Ickler noch darauf antwortet.

Comment: Erstaunlich was man über zwei simple Kürzungen alles schreiben kann. Ich bin beim Einkaufen - ich bin einkaufen. Wir gehen zum Schwimmen - wir gehen schwimmen. Was der Begriff absentiv besagen wiil, leuchtet mir überhaupt nicht ein.

Comment: @rogermue: Die Kürzung ist alles andere als trivial. Bei "Ich habe ihn kommen gesehen" kann ich nicht einfach das Partizip Perfekt weglassen, denn "Ich habe ihn kommen" ergibt keinen Sinn. Hier liegt also eine Besonderheit vor.

Answer (score 4):

Das Wichtigste ist wohl zu erkennen, dass es sich um besondere Konstruktionen handelt. Für jene mit *gehen* und *kommen* sind mir keine Bezeichnungen bekannt.

Ob "Absentiv" (für alle drei) als Bezeichnung sinnvoll ist, findet man wohl am besten heraus, indem man versucht, Gegenbeispiele zu finden. Das Beispiel `Ich komme demonstrieren.` drückt ebenfalls eine Abwesenheit des Subjekts von dessen "Topikort" aus (an den es grundsätzlich zurückkehren wird; Ausnahme: Ich gehe sterben).

Theodor Ickler macht hierzu eine interessante Bemerkung:

> Gegen die Abwesenheitsdeutung spricht noch folgendes: Gerade im paradigmatischen Fall, dem „Absentiv“ als Antwort auf die Frage *Wo ist er?*, kann die Antwort nicht die Abwesenheit ausdrücken, denn diese ist dem Fragenden ja bekannt, sie war die Voraussetzung seiner Frage.

Das ändert aber nichts an *seiner* Abwesenheit. Tatsächlich intrigierend ist aber folgendes:

> König weist selbst darauf hin, daß der „Absentiv“ nicht nur auf eine Frage wie *Wo ist er?* antwortet, sondern auch in Erzählungen und anderen Texten auftritt:
>   „Gestern, als ich in Saida arbeiten war, kam ein libanesischer Geheimdienstler und fragte, was ich hier tue“, beginnt er zu erzählen. (Beispiel von König)

In der Tat beschreibt dieser "Absentiv", wo das Subjekt damals *war*.
Hier kommt jedoch der Begriff "Topikort" ins Spiel. Die Person befand sich damals eben nicht an dem Ort, an dem sie gewöhnlicherweise anzutreffen gewesen wäre (zB in der Schweiz).

Ein anderer Weg wäre, zu überprüfen, ob man diese Konstruktion gängiger bezeichnen kann. Der Infinitiv kann kein verstecktes Adverb sein, da er mehr Bedeutung trägt als die Personalformen von *sein/kommen/gehen*, die außerdem zu so etwas wie Hilfszeitwörtern werden. Es könnte eine Ellipse sein, der das Partizip II fehlt. Dann muss nur noch der Infinitiv eingeordnet werden. Ich weiß nicht, wie man den Satz sonst noch auseinandernehmen könnte. "Absentiv" wäre wohl in jedem Fall die kürzere Alternative.

Abschließend soll bemerkt sein, dass etablierte Bezeichnungen auch nicht absolut sind: Der Dativ hat nicht immer mit Geben zu tun, der Akkustiv drückt kaum jemals eine Anzeige aus usw. (Vom Konjunktiv mal ganz abgesehen.)

---

<sup>[Icklers Artikel](http://www.sprachforschung.org/ickler/index.php?show=news&id=1278). Es handelt sich ebenfalls um Svenja König.</sup>

Comment: Und ich finde diese Antwort "intrigierend" ;-) Allein der letzte Absatz wäre +1 wert. Könntest Du vielleicht noch Quellenangaben hinzufügen? Insbesondere wäre für mich interessant, ob "König" in Icklers Zitat und Svenja König in meiner Antwort die selbe Person sind.

Comment: @Matthias: Da Ickler am Schluss seines Aufsatzes nur einmal König aufführt, nämlich Svenja, ist davon auszugehen.

Comment: @Veredomon Danke, hatte sich durch Grantwalzers Edit schon geklärt. Als ich den Kommentar schrieb, war der Link zum Artikel noch nicht mit dabei.

Answer (score 1):

Der Absentiv ist nicht "beschränkt auf das Verb 'sein'", vielmehr ist sein hier das Hilfsverb, um den Absentiv zu bilden. Das lässt sich an der Bedeutungsentleerung von "sein" ablesen: ich kann normalerweise etwa "blau sein", aber nicht eine Handlung sein. Insofern unterscheidet sich das auch von "ich gehe einkaufen" oder "ich komme einkaufen", bei der sich finites Verb und Infinitiv die semantische Bedeutung teilen. Formulieren wir das mal recht grotesk mit "tun" um:

1. Ich tu gehen und (tu) demonstrieren.
2. *Ich tu sein und (tu) einkaufen; denkbar wäre jedoch "Ich tu einkaufen sein"
3. Ich tu kommen und (tu) demonstrieren.

Die Konstruktion mit sein + Infinitiv ist also etwas besonders.
Hinzu kommt, dass man für den Absentiv einen sehr klaren Bereich definieren kann, wann er angebracht ist und wann nicht, einerseits, und dass seine Anwendung andererseits eine sehr eindeutige Bedeutung vermittelt. Damit ist er mit beispielsweise dem Futur vergleichbar, für das wir ebenfalls einen definierten Einsatzbereich haben und sofort seltsame bis ungrammatische Sätze produzieren, wenn wir diesen verlassen ("Ich werde vor zwei Wochen arbeiten").

Das mit Ickler/König kann ich nicht kommentieren, aber es liegt nahe, dass Svenja König gemeint ist, da Ickler eine Literaturliste am Schluss hat. Man möge mir den Regelverstoß verzeihen.

Comment: Mir scheint, als wäre *sein* nicht vollkommen "bedeutungsleer". *Ich einkaufen* wäre wohl am nächsten zu *ich kaufe ein*, was aber nicht gleichwertig mit *ich bin einkaufen* ist. Absurdes B: Zwei Personen im Supermarkt. Die eine fragt *Was machst du?* und bekommt als Antwort *Ich kaufe ein.* Ich kann mir *Ich bin einkaufen* nicht wirklich als Ersatz vorstellen.

Comment: Interessante Argumentation. Ich denke allerdings nicht, das "sein" komplett inhaltsleer ist, denn kommuniziert "Status Quo". Es setzt sich klar gegen das "strebende" von "kommen" und "gehen" ab. Zudem müsste nach der Logik auch das "sein" in "Ich bin im Bett" ein Hilfsverb sein, denn ich kann ja keine Ortsinformation sein. "Sein" spricht immer über den Status, egal ob bei Adjektiven, Ortsangaben oder Sachen wie der Rheinischen Verlaufsform. Das sinnentleerteste "Sein" ist noch das im Partizip, doch selbst da scheint Status durch.

Comment: Ich denke, dass "einkaufen" hier als Ortsinformation angesehen werden muss, die als Tätigkeitsinformation daher kommt. "Ich bin einkaufen" antwortet schließlich auf "wo bist du" sowohl wie auch auf "was machst du?". Für gehen und kommen lassen sich die analoge Fragen finden. Ergo... es ist nicht inhaltsleer und daher kein Hilfsverb. Übrigens... du musst wenn dann "einkaufen" ersetzen... "Ich tue im Bett/einkaufen sein". Bloss weil das ein Verb ist, ist das andere ja nicht gleich ein Hilfsverb... siehe "Ich kann kommen"... vielleicht sollte man "sein" ja spasseshalber mal als Modalverb analysi.

Comment: Man könnte sich in der Tat darum streiten, wie viel semantischen Gehalt "sein" überhaupt hat, abseitig von seltenen Verwendungen wie "Ich denke, also bin ich".

Comment: (Sorry, wusste nicht, dass Enter sendet) Man könnte sich in der Tat darum streiten, wie viel semantischen Gehalt "sein" überhaupt hat, abseitig von seltenen Verwendungen wie "Ich denke, also bin ich". In allen anderen Fällen erfüllt es grammatikalische Zwecke (Kopula, Zustandspassiv, am-Progressiv, Perfekt...). In "Ich bin einkaufen" hat "sein" keine andere Bedeutung außer dass es den Absentiv bildet. So wie es ja auch keine Bedeutung in "ich bin am arbeiten/ich bin gelaufen" hat; natürlich versteckt sich in beidem ein gewisser Status (Zustand des gerade arbeitens/Zustand des gelaufen seins).