# Helping Verbs, or even the verb „sein“ + Infinitives In German? (i.e. werden)

Tags: sentence-structure, verb-usage, infinitive, past, future

I am curious, in English it is possible to convey past, present, and future through helping verbs and/or just infinitives.

*I did drink* -- *I drunk/drank* (my dialect says "drunk;") this is Past.

*I drink;* this is Present

*I will drink;* this is Future

*or also: *I shall/must drink* for imperativicity or determination.

---

I am awares in German, *„Ich **werde** trinken“* is possible for: *"I will drink* (Naught: *'I will to drink/I want to drink --'* such be *‚Ich will trinken... ‘*)" The same I am aware that both languages essentially have mostly the same grammar (all things given,) so also is there a helping verb in German for past tense to maintain an infinitive, and, be it possible, how shall one combine *sein* plus an infinitive as I am awares *„Ich bin trinken... “* is either not common or not exactly acceptable.

---

I thank you all in advance.

Comment: *"both languages essentially have mostly the same grammar"*. Only they do from an extraterrestrial perspective.

Comment: I disagree, english is mainly less inflected -- both are west germanic languages, the grammar is much the same; I can't think of a single thing that is not the same.

Comment: The use of *do* is an English peculiarity.

Comment: This is true, but I am curious if there is an equivalent term in german. I don't think _‚‚tun‘‘_ can be used. I highly doubt a word would be the same if german doth have a word for this particular case.

Comment: Your attempt at archaic sounding language does not help understanding, and it is frankly annoying.

Comment: I wasn't attempting archaic language, thank you very much. I was speaking in a normal english as my dialect has, in the which it is fully acceptable to use early modern english. If I were "attempting" to use early modern english, this whole thing would be in early modern english.

Comment: My apologies. I am curious then: What is your dialect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a form of **past auxiliary(seemingly) + infinitive** in German that *from a pure grammatical view* would be congruent with what you are looking for, but it means something entirely different:

> Ich war schwimmen

This does **not** translate to "I was swimming", but rather to something along the lines of "I was at a place somewhere else to swim".

This construct is also not limited to "sein" and "haben", but can also be used with verbs of movement:

> Ich gehe schwimmen.
>
> Mein Sohn ging spielen.

(My son went to a place somewhere else to play)

This even works with "sein" like in

> Ich war gestern nicht arbeiten.

(Which doesn't mean "I haven't been working yesterday" but rather "I wasn't at the place where I normally work yesterday" - I cannot find a more literal translation to bring the difference across)

Note the verbs "sein" + "haben" used here are not used as auxiliaries, but rather are full verbs

Comment: The only thing I can think of that that would still be literal enough to be that and carry the same meaning would be:

I was _at_ swim/ _the_ swimming --

I was yesterday not _at_ work/ _the_ work(ing/s)

Comment: Well, literally it would be *I go to swim* - Which is not what I'd call correct English, or *I go to work*, but that's a substantive as well in English.

Comment: `Ich war schwimmen.` doesn't explicitely state to be at a special *place* for swimming (as it could have happend in your bathtup). Of course, you have to be at a place, where swimming is possible, to swim, but that's not the point of that sentence. `Ich war schwimmen.` rather emphasizes, that I did the whole process associated with swimming (maybe going to a special place, changing clothes, the actual swimming, drying up afterwards, maybe going back).

So, the construct `sein`+`infinitive` with `sein` in past does also work semantically as the OP thinks, but it hase heavy side connotations.

Answer (score 3):

The German »Perfekt« tense is built with *haben/sein* + Partizip II (which is the same as the past participle in English).

So in your case: »Ich habe [getrunken](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:trinken)«

An infinitive would be wrong. But »Ich bin trinken« is also possible in colloquial language. It’s a special grammar form called »[Adsentiv](http://www.deutschegrammatik20.de/2013/08/28/fachliteratur-absentiv/)« which responds to questions like »Where are you?« or »What are you doing?«

Comment: I do not think that “bin trinken” is properly described as short for “bin trinken gegangen”. https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15529/absentiv-oder-doch-was-anderes

Comment: Ich danke Ihnen. I did know that, but I do thank you, I suppose it is truly not possible that german has a word equal to "do" to form a past tense with an infinitive.

Comment: And neither does "Ich bin Trinken" imply that you're a heavy drinker, only that drinking is your current occupation. (As in what you do at the moment, not what you do for a living.)

Answer (score 2):

There is also the grammatical form `tun`+`infinitive of verb`. It is lowly valued and associated with people not capable of or not caring of correct grammar. (Which is why it's most often used with `du`.) Its usage is probably dependend on dialect as well. It is semantically equivalent to the verb itself but has the syntactical difference, that only `tun` is conjugated. So this forms behaves just as the usual English version of `do`+`infinitive of verb`.

> Ich tu trinken. → Ich trinke.
>   Tust du trinken? → Drinkst du?
>   Ich tat trinken? → Ich trank.

Answer (score 0):

In German when you want to say "I am drinking.", you say "Ich trinke." — the present works as present continuous. You should not use "Ich bin trinken.".
The Germans do not often use "Ich werde trinken", that is only written not spoken. You can use the present but you must explain when, like for example "Ich trinke am Morgen.", so that people understand that you are talking about the future.

Comment: Futur is not only used in written language, but its oral usage is heavily dependend on the sociolect.