# Kann man sagen: Großmutter ist einkaufen? Oder Großmutter kauft ein?

Tags: grammatical-case

Was sind die Unterschiede und welche Grammatik ist es?
Dankeschön

Comment: Wenn du dich für die grammatischen Hintergründe interessierst, schau dir mal den [Wikipedia-Eintrag zum Absentiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absentiv) an. Ich kann mich auch noch an einige vorherige Fragen dazu erinnern.

Comment: Siehe auch https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15529/absentiv-oder-doch-was-anderes

Answer (score 2):

Versuch einer einfachen Erklärung:

> Großmutter ist einkaufen

wird normalerweise auf die Fragen "wo ist Großmutter?" bzw. "warum ist Großmutter nicht hier?" geantwortet. (In den Kommentaren kam dazu der Begriff "Absentiv" auf - Es lohnt sich, den nachzulesen). Im Prinzip wird mit einer Tätigkeit geantwortet, obwohl nach einem Ort gefragt wurde. Das funktioniert natürlich nur, wenn die Tätigkeit regelmäßig an der gleichen Stelle ausgeführt wird, also klar ist, an welchem Ort Großmutter normalerweise einkaufen geht, oder es gar nicht darum geht, wo Großmutter genau ist, sondern nur "warum sie nicht da ist".

> Großmutter kauft ein

wäre dagegen eher eine Antwort auf die Frage "was macht Großmutter?"

Answer (score 1):

Die Sätze

> Großmutter ist einkaufen.
>   Lukas ist arbeiten.

werden von einigen Fachleuten als typisches Beispiel einer Konstruktion angesehen, die [Absentiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absentiv) genannt wird. Damit wir ausgedrückt, dass das Subjekt des Satzes sich nicht am Ort des Sprechers befindet, weil es an einem anderen Ort einer bestimmten Tätigkeit nachgeht. Gebildet wird diese Konstruktion wie folgt:

- Subjekt
- Eine Form des Hilfsverbs *»sein«*, die in Übereinstimmung mit dem Subjekt konjugiert wird.
- Ein Verb im Infinitiv, das jene Tätigkeit ausdrückt, der das Subjekt nachgeht.

Eine Angabe des konkreten Ortes, an dem sich das Subjekt befindet, ist nicht erforderlich, schadet aber auch nicht. Die Konstruktion drückt an sich schon aus, dass das Subjekt abwesend ist.

Weitere Beispiele:

> Klaus ist joggen.
>   Der Verdächtige war zur Tatzeit im Schotterteich baden.

Das Subjekt kann sogar dann *»ich«* sein, wenn die Form von *»sein«* im Präsens steht. In diesem Fall wird damit eine Handlung in der nahen Zukunft ausgedrückt:

> Tschüß! Ich bin jetzt arbeiten.

Der Sprecher verabschiedet sich und wird umgehend den Adressaten seiner Rede verlassen um zu arbeiten.

---

Die Sätze

> Großmutter kauft ein.
>   Lukas arbeitet.

sind ganz normale Aussagen, die nur aus einem Subjekt und einem Verb bestehen, also ganz ohne Objekte und sonstige Beifügungen auskommen. Trennbare Verben erscheinen in diesem Fall in ihrer getrennten Form (*einkaufen → kauft ein*), wodurch der eigentliche Zweiwortsatz ein drittes Wort bekommt, das aber eben ein Teil des Verbs ist.

Der semantische Unterschied zum Absentiv besteht darin, dass hier keine Abwesenheit des Subjekts zum Ausdruck gebracht wird. Dieser Zustand würde zwar der Aussage des Satzes nicht widersprechen, folgt aber nicht zwingend aus der Aussage dieses Satzes.

Tatsächlich lässt diese einfache Konstruktion ohne weiteren Kontext jede beliebige Interpretation der Situation zu. So kann z.B. aus

> Tschüß! Ich arbeite jetzt.

Nicht zwingend geschlossen werden, dass der Sprecher den Adressaten verlassen wird um zu arbeiten. Denkbar ist nämlich auch, dass der Sprecher die angesprochene Person mit dem Gruß dazu bewegen will, den Sprecher zu verlassen, während er seine bereits betriebene Arbeit fortsetzen will.

Answer (score 0):

> Großmutter ist einkaufen

bedeutet, dass die Großmutter aktuell beim Einkaufen ist.

> Großmutter kauft ein

kann das Gleiche bedeuten, kann aber auch heißen, dass es generell die Großmutter ist, die einkauft, und nicht z. B. der Großvater.

Eine weitere Möglichkeit ist, dass sich dieser Satz auf einen Tagesplan bezieht.

> Plan für heute: Großmutter kauft ein, Mutter kocht, Vater isst.

Answer (score 0):

> Großmutter kauft ein.

ist ein einfacher Aussagesatz.

> Großmutter ist einkaufen.

ist eine Ellipse. Vollständig würde der Satz lauten:

> Großmutter ist einkaufen gegangen.