# Wie ist die Struktur von "warst du schon spazieren?" zu verstehen?

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality, infinitive

Woher kommt die Struktur eines Satzes wie:

1. *Warst du schon mit dem Hund spazieren?*

Geschrieben hätte ich entweder:

2. *Bist du schon mit dem Hund spazieren gegangen?*

oder

3. *Warst du schon mit dem Hund am/beim Spazieren?*

Diese Zusammenseztung vom "sein" und einem Infinitiv, und zwar ohne "zu", erkenne und verstehe ich aber nicht ganz genau. Ist sie in anderen Fällen gängig? Wären die anderen 2 oben genannten Sätze auch richtig gewesen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Spazieren sein* aus Satz (1) ist der Infinitiv des sog. [**Absentivs**](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absentiv), vgl. [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15529/absentiv-oder-doch-was-anderes). Dieser kann in Form des Hilfsverbes *sein* beliebig konjugiert werden:

> - Du bist spazieren. *(Präsens)*
> - **Du warst spazieren.** *(Präteritum)*
> - Du bist spazieren gewesen. *(Präsensperfekt)*
> - Du warst spazieren gewesen. *(Präteritumsperfekt)*
> - Du wirst spazieren sein. *(Futur I)*
> - Du wirst spazieren gewesen sein. *(Futur II)*

Satz (2) ist das normale Präsensperfekt von *spazieren gehen* (Infinitiv Perfekt Aktiv: *spazieren gegangen sein*):

> - Du gehst spazieren. *(Präsens)*
> - Du gingst spazieren. *(Präteritum)*
> - **Du bist spazieren gegangen.** *(Präsensperfekt)*
> - Du warst spazieren gegangen. *(Präteritumsperfekt)*

Satz (3) ist das sog. [am-Progressiv](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Am-Progressiv) (auch als *Rheinische Verlaufsform* bezeichnet) im Präteritum:

> - Du bist am Spazieren. *(Präsens)*
> - **Du warst am Spazieren.** *(Präteritum)*
> - Du bist am Spazieren gewesen. *(Präsensperfekt)*
> - Du warst am Spazieren gewesen. *(Präteritumsperfekt)*

Comment: Bei 3 bin ich immer am Zusammenzucken ;)

Comment: @choXer: ... zusammen am Zucken!